# The quickest way to delete a function argument in Vim

Tags: vim

If I have the following code:

```
foo->call(bar, baz->widget);
```

With cursor on "b" in "baz" or on "w" in "widget", how would I quickly delete the argument at the cursor?

```
foo->call(bar);
```

It can be any argument (first, last, or in the middle).

Answer (score 11):

With my [omap-param plugin](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-cpp/blob/master/plugin/omap-param.vim), just type `di,` or `da,`.

It won't be bothered by other brackets. For instance, in `f(a+g(42, "string")), foobar)`, from "a" to "g", `da,` will just leave `foobar` in f call.

Answer (score 8):

For the first argument, this key-combination goes to opening parenthesis, and deletes everything up to the next comma, including the space after it:

`T(df,x`

For a middle argument, this key-combination goes to the previous comma, and deletes it and everything until the next comma:

`F,dt,`

For the last argument, this key-combination goes to the previous comma, and deletes it and everything until the closing parenthesis:

`F,dt)`

-- or --

You can write your own macro to do this sort of thing. A similar example is [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Move_function_parameters_with_macro).

Comment: `B` only takes you back to the beginning of baz, not back to the comma, and if there's no space, it'd go too far. Almost, though!

Comment: This breaks with `foo->call(bar, baz->widget());`

Comment: Actually, the first one will leave an extra comma. Working on a solution that will delete the comma efficiently as well.

Comment: There we go, that should do it.

Answer (score 4):

[targets.vim](https://github.com/wellle/targets.vim#argument-text-objects) is a further plugin that provides `aa` and `ia` (which fixes also missing default behaviour of builtin text-objects, compare discussion on [TextObjectify](https://github.com/paradigm/TextObjectify))

Answer (score 2):

[vim-argumentative](https://github.com/PeterRincker/vim-argumentative) is another plugin option that provides `a,` and `i,` text objects and more.

Answer (score 1):

?,enter    to move to the previous ','

d/,enter   to delete to the next ','

no plugins required

you may need to prepend the search terms with a number in the case of template params:

void foo( sometype a, some_template_type< sometype, sometype > b, sometype c )

or you could press '.' however many comma seperations you want rid of.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to make something that works consistently for the first or last cases.

Something like this will work reasonably well:

```
/(\)|,)
dT,
```

This will find the next `,` or `)` character, then delete back to the character after the previous `,`. It won't work for the first parameter and won't work as intended if your parameter includes a `)` or `,`, for example if there is a function call in there.

You could put this into a macro:

```
qd
/(\)|,)
dT,
q
```

Then to reuse, go to the parameter you would like to delete and run the macro:

```
@d
```