# VIM Delete Standard Scripting Word Groups

Tags: vim

How would you use VIM to delete a word group, which includes white space characters, but is a standard grouping you would want to access when scripting? Specifically, when you have your cursor over some part of the following text, how would delete `help="initialize, lines, h2, derivs, tt, history",` from below.  Maybe one would need to create specific mappings.  But on the other hand, it seems pretty natural to want to access text like this if you are using VIM to edit scripting programs.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("task", help="initialize, lines, h2, derivs, tt, history", default='yes')
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [The quickest way to delete a function argument in Vim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709742/the-quickest-way-to-delete-a-function-argument-in-vim)

Answer (score 1):

If you are inside the `"` you want to delete, I would use:

<kbd>d</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>W</kbd>

If you were above `help=`, I would use something like:

<kbd>d</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

to remove everything until you encounter `default`, followed by a few <kbd>x</kbd>, and left-wise motion, to remove the remaining characters.

I don't really think a new mapping is needed, but your experience may vary.

Comment: I mistakenly downvoted your answer and I had to do a minor edit to be able to re-upvote. Sorry to bother you.

Comment: @romainl: No problem, I was just wondering if someone was hating text objects.

Answer (score 1):

Vim has a variety of *text objects* built-in, e.g. `da"` deletes quoted text (including the quotes; `di"` keeps the quotes). See `:help text-objects` for more information.

There are some plugins, e.g. [textobj-user - Support for user-defined text objects](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2100) and my own [CountJump plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3130) that make it easy to define your own, "special" text objects. Also, you'll find many such text objects on [vim.org](http://www.vim.org/). Based on your example, [argtextobj.vim - Text-object like motion for arguments](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2699) may be exactly what you need here.

Comment: Shameless plug for my vim plugin, Argumentative, https://github.com/PeterRincker/vim-argumentative

Answer (score 1):

What makes sense from Vim's perspective and according to its design goals is to provide small and generic elements and a few rules to combine them in order to achieve higher level tasks. It does quite a good job, I'd say, with its numerous text-objects and motions but we always have to repeat domain-specific tasks and that's exactly where Vim's extensibility comes into play. It is where users and plugin authors fill the gap with custom mappings/object/functions and… plugins.

It is fairly easy, for example, to record a macro and map it for later reuse. Or create a quick and dirty custom text-object…

The following snippet should work with your sample.

```
xnoremap aa /\v["'][,)]/e<CR>o?\v\s+\w+\=<CR>
onoremap aa :normal vaa<CR>
```

With it, you can do `daa`, `caa`, `yaa` and `vaa` from anywhere within *that* argument.

Obviously, this solution is extremely specific and making it more generic would most certainly involve a bit more thought but there are already relatively smart solutions floating around, as in Ingo's answer.